# how to set up internet wire connection on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: internet-connection

I install Ubuntu 12.04 on VMWare on D drive of Window 7. Now, Window 7 have internet connection but Ubuntu have no internet connection. In window 7, I use automatically detect proxy with wired connection. It's ok on Window7. Why it doesn't on Ubuntu. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Simply selecting NAT in the VM's options should work for basic network access - assuming that the NAT networking was set up when VMware (whatever?) was installed. more info can be found in [here](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_nat.html)

Comment: Yes, I use only NAT. Before Ubuntu, I installed Window XP on that VMware. At that time, its ok in internet connection. I didn't make any changes. I can't find it out.

Comment: which version of VMware you are using?

Comment: please refer [this](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/402577) link, it might be help you.

Comment: My VMWare version is 6.5.